# Is there a way in spark ar to convert scalars to string through the patch editor and not scripting?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

I'm trying to set a scalar value that I get from script into a string through the patch editor to put it into a 2Dtext object. I can't do it via script because I need it to look like its counting up. does anyone know how to convert a scalarvalue to an int by only using the patch editor?[image of what I'm doing / have tried.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRGGf.png)[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrblU.png)

Comment: Please provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example or add more detailed code snippets on what you have tried. Thank you.

Comment: but there is pretty much no code used. thats why I asked about through the patch editor.